# How can I refactor this jquery code for a NOOB

Tags: jquery, refactoring

I have the following code that I can't seem to refactor:

```
    //opens some drop downs
    $('#proofreading').mouseover(function(){
                $('.proofreading .accordion-body').collapse('show');
    });


    $('#edit').mouseover(function(){
                $('.edit .accordion-body').collapse('show');
    });


    $('#on_time').mouseover(function(){
                $('.on_time .accordion-body').collapse('show');
    });
```

Here is the code in the html:

```
<div class='content-more'>
<br>
<span id='proofreading'>
Read More...
</span>
</div>
<div class='accordion proofreading'>
<div class='accordion-group'>
<div class='accordion-body collapse'>
<div class='accordion-inner'>
<p class='content-desc'>
<br>
When your work is proofread at EAPI we will go over your text word by word, line by line correcting the spelling, punctuation, grammar, terminology, jargon, and semantics.  As a result, your writing will be clear, correct, concise, comprehensible, and consistent: the <b>EAPI 5C standard</b>.
</p>
</div>
<br>
<span class='content-more close-accordion'>
close
</span>
</div>
</div>
</div>

<div class='content-more'>
<br>
<span id='edit'>
read more...
</span>
</div>
<div class='accordion edit'>
<div class='accordion-group'>
<div class='accordion-body collapse'>
<div class='accordion-inner'>
<p class='content-desc'>
<br>
When your work is edited at EAPI we will check and improve the formatting, style and accuracy of the text without altering the intended meaning.
</p>
<span class='content-more close-accordion'>
close
</span>
</div>
</div>
</div>

<div class='content-more'>
<br>
<span id='on_time'>
Read more...
</span>
</div>
<div class='accordion on_time'>
<div class='accordion-group'>
<div class='accordion-body collapse'>
<div class='accordion-inner'>
<p class='content-desc'>
<br>
When your work is proofread at EAPI we will go over your text word by word, line by line correcting the spelling, punctuation, grammar, terminology, jargon, and semantics.  As a result, your writing will be clear, correct, concise, comprehensible, and consistent: the <b>EAPI 5C standard</b>.
</p>
</div>
<br>
<span class='content-more close-accordion'>
close
</span>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

How can I refactor the code so I don't need the id's and can just use a class as well as reduce the need for three jquery statements.

Comment: I would recommend starting by changing the HTML markup. Use Ids to encapsulate the related content and you won't have to make use of the classes `on_time`, `edit` and `proofreading` to identify again the related content.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `class="accordion-header'` to the `proofreading`, `edit`, and `on_time` DIVs. Then:

```
$(".accordion-header").mouseover(function() {
    $('.' + this.id + ' .accordion-body').collapse('show');
});
```